# Is jenkins a code inspector?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Hi im using jenkins but i need to ask if it is a code ispector ?
Or does it has more functions that I can use because I cant find them and its important ?

Comment: See Sonar and the Jenkins plugin: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=116359341

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins itself is not a code inspector.  It is more of a [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server that provides a plugin API so that it can be expanded to do different things.  There are alot of plugins available, so it really depends on your language and what you want your inspector to do ( static analysis, code coverage, etc )

A quick search provided this page [Jenkins Plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins)

I have Jenkins installed ( I do not have network access to it at the moment ) and it has a plugins page you can go to to see the available plugins.  That would probably be the most up to date list.

We currently use Jenkins with a number of plugins to do builds and analysis on every commit.  If you want to just run an analysis, you may want a standalone analysis tool.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me a good code inspector where i put mi code and it helps me see if its ok with the layers and all ??

Comment: @user2109088 Language?  What kind of inspection?